# Getting value from yaml object in file

Tags: go, yaml

I'm getting time to learn Go, and I'm having a problem dealing with yaml file.

this is my yaml file

```
--- 
endpoints: 
  service1: 
    url: "https://service1.com"
    frequency: 2
    interval: 1
  service2: 
    url: "https://service2.com"
    frequency: 3
    interval: 2
```

My go code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "reflect"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

// Config define estrutura do arquivo de configuração
type Config struct {
    Endpoint map[string]interface{} `yaml:"endpoints"`
}

func main() {
    yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.yml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading YAML file: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    var yamlConfig Config
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &yamlConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error parsing YAML file: %s\n", err)
    }

    for k := range yamlConfig.Endpoint {
        nm := reflect.ValueOf(yamlConfig.Endpoint[k])
        for _, key := range nm.MapKeys() {
            strct := nm.MapIndex(key)
            fmt.Println(key.Interface(), strct.Interface())
        }
    }

}

// PingEndpoint acessa os endpoint informados
func PingEndpoint(url string, frequency, interval int) {
    // do something

}
```

Is there a better way to define the Config structure without using interface? And is really necessary use reflect do get properties of a `service1` or exist a better whey to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, an `interface{}` is used in this situation if you don't know the structure. In this case, the structure appears to be fixed:

```
type Service struct {
   URL string `yaml:"url"`
   Frequency int `yaml:"frequency"`
   Interval int `yaml:"interval"`
}

type Config struct {
    Endpoint map[string]Service `yaml:"endpoints"`
}
```

For your second question, you no longer need to deal with unknown fields after you do this, but even if you had interface{}, you can use type assertions (type yaml library unmarshals yaml into a map[interface{}]interface{}):

```
for k := range yamlConfig.Endpoint {
     if mp, ok:=yamlConfig.Endpoint[k].(map[interface{}]interface{}); ok {
         for key, value:=range mp {
        }
    }
}
```